# Why is there small text randomly on the review history?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Some - about 2 thirds of the reviews - have got larger text, and the other third has small text - why? It is staring to really bug my OCDness that it is random - not even  reviewed, no action needed (see the 2nd and 3rd circled ones), or how long ago.

[image]

Comment: I bet those are deleted, can you click on them?

Comment: Nope, they're still there.

Comment: So you can click on the title?

Comment: Yep, and it takes me to the still open question.

Comment: strange, all the ones with little text I can't click on...

Comment: Some I can't - Cd rom file is MT and hew support... but this question is active: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367260/i-am-logged-out-immediately-after-logging-in/499157#499157

Comment: The titles in the smaller font are links to answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the smaller links point to answers. Gotta love sharing styles across multiple views!

This will be fixed in the next build - the answer links will look the same as question links since distinguishing between the types of posts on this view isn't terribly important.